# In browser library document do we have anything similar to Get WebElement keyword?

Tags: robotframework

Do we have anything similar to Get WebElement in browser library doc ? Get WebElement keyword is there in selenium library .. i need to similar to that in browser library for my test case ..Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Get Elements' keyword from BrowserLibrary is comparable to 'Get Webelements' from SeleniumLibrary:

https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Get%20Elements